# Trigger tab with data-toggle and href

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, tabs

I have the tab-based page with a first tab open when the page is loaded.
The problem is that I want to create a link to open and scroll to some of the other tabs.

Here is the Tab code:

```
<li><a href="#advantages" class="tab-link" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">ADVANTAGES</a></li>
```

It works when you add #something at the end of the URL, but the problem is that you can not trigger the tab opening from button or link on the same page.

**Example:** If you want to lead someone from the page to open tab different than first.

**The Question is:** Is there a way to trigger and open another tab different than the first one

Comment: Please create a working example of the problem you are facing

Comment: I do not thing is neeed. I just want to know can I trigger this kind of type of tab with jquery or javascript?